# Can I pass a variable from one twig to another twig deeper in render array?

Tags: 8, theming

does anybody know if/how I can pass a variable from a twig higher in the render array, to one of it's descendants? I'd like to have a pure twig solution.

**Use case:**

I inject a css class into `views-view.html.twig` in configuration. Depending on this, I would like to decide in a lower `views-view-fields.html.twig`, how to generate fields. I would create a bunch of macros - then import them dynamically depending on the css class.

**Alternative solutions I'd like to avoid:**

- I do not want to rely on machine names and create lot of `views-view-fields--.....html.twig` files. Super ugly, not scalable, not maintainable.
- I also don't want to create a solution which goes through all layers and maintain twigs, php hooks, configuration values and write documentation which pleads it not to fall apart.

**Desired is:**

I want this to be a configuration thing which docks 1:1 onto twig-filesystem. For that I need to make a string available to a twig deeper down in the render pipeline. How??

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach, Views templates don't contain many render arrays. Fields are rendered by handlers. Not only fields, all things you can configure in Views UI are handlers and if you need more options to configure then extend Views with more handler plugins, contrib or custom.

Comment: Well, that might be true, but I don't have the time to learn a whole technology stack :) Even if I do learn it, the guy which comes after me, might not be there yet.
If you collapse time, and think away the php part, it just one giant render array which is devoured by a cascade of twig files...